# Magento 2.1: Invoke urlBuilder->getUrl() in a controller in a custom module

Tags: magento2, module, controllers, magento-2.1

I think my issue might have to do with dependency injection, which I'm still trying to grab the concept.

What I would like to do is to be able to get the URL using `getUrl()` function from `Magento\Framework\UrlInterface` object.

So this what I have so far.

1. Create a functional controller and set up route. It is accessible via web browser and has `execute()` function defined.
2. Add use `Magento\Framework\UrlInterface`; in a controller class
3. Add a protected variable `$urlBuilder`
4. Add a constructor like below

   ```
   public function __construct(
       UrlInterface $urlBuilder
   ) {
       $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
   }
   ```

The follow error is thrown when I go to the URL that the controller is mapped to.

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Tester\ExamplePaymentGateway\Controller\Example\AbstractExample\Start::__construct() must implement interface Magento\Framework\UrlInterface, instance of Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context given, called in var/generation/Tester/ExamplePaymentGateway/Controller/Example/Start/Interceptor.php on line 14 and defined in app/code/Tester/ExamplePaymentGateway/Controller/Example/AbstractExample/Start.php:24
>   Stack trace:
>   #0 var/generation/Tester/ExamplePaymentGateway/Controller/Example/Start/Interceptor.php(14):
>   Tester\ExamplePaymentGateway\Controller\Example\AbstractExample\Start->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context), Object(Magento\Customer\Model\Session\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Checkout\Model\Session\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory), Object(Magento\Paypal\Model\Express\Checkout\Factory), Object(Magento\Framework\Session\Ge in app/code/Tester/ExamplePaymentGateway/Controller/Example/AbstractExample/Start.php on line 24

Am I missing some step before I can inject the URL builder or any other objects (let's say quote, cart, or payment helper)?

Comment: Tried to remove `var/generation`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your controller extend `Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action` you should  follow rules of creation of the controller. So you should implement dependency injection of the parent class constructor (`Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action`):

```
/**
 * @param Context $context
 */
public function __construct(Context $context)
{
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->_objectManager = $context->getObjectManager();
    $this->_eventManager = $context->getEventManager();
    $this->_url = $context->getUrl();
    $this->_actionFlag = $context->getActionFlag();
    $this->_redirect = $context->getRedirect();
    $this->_view = $context->getView();
    $this->messageManager = $context->getMessageManager();
}
```

Your construct method should look like this after a modifications:

```
/**
 * @param Context $context
 * @param UrlInterface $urlBuilder
 */
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    UrlInterface $urlBuilder
) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
}
```

**NOTE**: do not forget to remove old `var/generation` directory after implementing of modifications, because there are stored the generated files of controllers.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.. I tried to add the construct method on my controller, but got the following error: Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Tester\ExamplePaymentGateway\Controller\Example\AbstractExample\Start::__construct() must be an instance of Tester\ExamplePaymentGateway\Controller\Example\AbstractExample\Context, instance of Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context given, called in /home/magento_user/public_html/var/generation/Tester/ExamplePaymentGateway/Controller/Example/Start/Interceptor.php on line 14

Comment: @frostshoxx Most likely you created the class of a context and added it in the abstract controller. It is necessary to see a code completely.

Comment: The issue was me not creating an abstract controller. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 13):

actually from controller you can use

```
$this->_url->getUrl('yourmoduleurl/index/index')
```